# Using custom states, onCreateDrawableState never called

Tags: android, imageview, selector

I have an ImageView subclass with custom states.  onCreateDrawableState is not called when the widget is instantiated and the image graphic does not appear in my layout.  Even if I call refreshDrawableState(), it does not work.  I single stepped through the latter and the View code is expecting m_background to be already set (it's still null in my case).

What am I missing that would cause m_background to have an initial value?

**values/attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable 
    name="toggle_states">

    <attr name="state_left" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="state_right" format="boolean"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**drawables/selector_toggle.xml**

```
<selector 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test" >

   <item 
     myapp:state_left="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_left" />

   <item 
     myapp:state_right="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_right" />
 </selector>
```

**Toggle.java**

```
public class Toggle extends ImageView 
{
  private static final int[] STATE_LEFT = {R.attr.state_left};
  private static final int[] STATE_RIGHT= {R.attr.state_right};

  public enum State {LEFT, RIGHT};
  private State state = State.LEFT;

  public Toggle (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
  {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public int[] onCreateDrawableState (int extraSpace) 
  {
    final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState (extraSpace + 1);
    if (state == State.LEFT)
      mergeDrawableStates (drawableState, STATE_LEFT);
    else
      mergeDrawableStates (drawableState, STATE_RIGHT);
    return drawableState;
  }
}
```

**some_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

  ...

  <com.example.test.Toggle
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    myapp:state_left="true"
  />

  ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: adding a background image to the Toggle in some_layout.xml solves the problem.  But it also defeats the encapsulation.  So I abandoned this technique all together and simply put code in Toggle.java to set the background image per state.  Takes just a few lines a code and is so much simpler than using all the res files shown above!

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle.xml"` in com.example.test.Toggle

```
<com.example.test.Toggle
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle.xml"
        myapp:state_left="true"
      />
```